# How do I trigger an Airflow DAG via the REST API?

Tags: airflow

The 1.10.0 documentation says I should be able to make a POST against /api/experimental/dags//dag_runs to trigger a DAG run, but instead when I do this, I receive an error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

Answer (score 12):

To make this work, I figured out that I needed to send an empty JSON string in the body:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://airflow.dyn.fa.disney.com/api/experimental/dags/people_data/dag_runs \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -d '{}'
```

Answer (score 0):

With the stable API REST/Airflow 2.x, I used:

From CLI:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dags/taskflow_api/dagRuns" 
-H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{}" \
--user "username:password"
```

With library request https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

auth = ('username', 'password')

body = {
       "conf": {}
}

response = requests.post(url=url,
                         headers=headers, 
                         auth=auth, 
                         data=json.dumps(body)
                        )
```

Note: to check which authentication backend is currently set, see this link https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/api.html

I hope it is very useful

Regards